# Encoding the values of a square matrix into a periodic complex function

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, representation-theory

It is my understanding that if we have a complex-valued signal / vector $X = \begin{bmatrix}a & b & c & d\end{bmatrix}$, then there exists a function $\psi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that if $x$ is integral, $\displaystyle\psi(\frac{x}{4})$ is the $x_{th}$ entry in $X$, and $$\begin{align}\psi(x) &= \psi(x + 1)\end{align}$$, which can be computed by multiplying $X$ by the inverse of the $4 \times 4$ DFT matrix, then treating the entries as coefficients in a $q$-series, where $$q(x) = \text{exp}(2\pi ix)$$. Thus
$$\psi(x) = \frac{a+b+c+d}{4} + \frac{a-b-ci+di}{4}q + \frac{a+b-c-d}{4}q^2 + \frac{a-b+ci-di}{4}q^3$$ (I omitted the derivation because I couldn't figure out how to write a square matrix here). The question:

> Is there a process by which, given an $n \times n$ matrix $M$, we can compute a function $\psi: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $\displaystyle\psi(\frac{a + bi}{n})$ is equal to the $b_{th}$ entry in the $a_{th}$ row of $M$, and $\psi(s) = \psi(s+1)$?

If helpful, $\displaystyle\psi(0) = \psi(\frac{a}{n}) = \psi(\frac{bi}{n})$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ may be assumed.

The tag `representation-theory` was added because I am concerned with the character tables of groups. In particular, such a $\psi$ exists for the character table of the cyclic group of order $n$: $\displaystyle\psi_n(a + bi) = \text{exp}(2\pi i abn)$. Here is a domain coloring for $\psi_4$ and $\psi_7$. Here the domain of the function has been changed from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\frac{a+bi}{n} \forall_{a,b} \in \mathbb{Z}$, as these are the only inputs we care about, using the map $\displaystyle\varphi(s) = \frac{\text{round}(sn)}{n}$; but naturally it is defined everywhere and $\psi(s) = \psi(s+1)$ holds.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Method

The process is the same. Our matrix belongs to the vector space $\mathbb{C}^n \times \mathbb{C}^n$. For illustration let $M$ be a $4 \times 4$ matrix. Then it is a vector $$\begin{bmatrix}
A &B &C &D
\end{bmatrix}$$ with elements in $\mathbb{C}^4$. Compute $\psi(x)$ as in the OP by multiplying by the inverse DFT matrix to obtain the $q$-series $$\psi_x(x) = \frac{A+B+C+D}{4} + \frac{A-B+Ci-Di}{4}q + \frac{A+B-C-D}{4}q^2 + \frac{A-B-Ci+Di}{4}q^3$$. Now, $\psi_x:\mathbb{R} \to (\mathbb{C}^4)^*$, so the image is a vector $$\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha &\beta &\gamma &\delta
\end{bmatrix}^T$$Where $\alpha, \beta\dots$ are functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$:$$\begin{align}
\alpha(x) &= A + Aq + Aq^2 + Aq^3 \\
\beta(x) &= B - Bq + Bq^2 - Bq^3 \\
\gamma(x) &= C + Ciq - Cq^2 - Ciq^3 \\
\delta(x) &= D - Diq - Dq^2 + Diq^3 \\
\end{align}$$. We take the transpose and once again compute the inverse DFT to obtain a function $$\begin{align}
\psi_{xy}(x,y) &= \frac{\alpha(x) + \beta(x) + \gamma(x) + \delta(x)}{4} \\
&+ \frac{\alpha(x) - \beta(x) + i\gamma(x) - i\delta(x)}{4}r \\
&+ \frac{\alpha(x) + \beta(x) - \gamma(x) - \delta(x)}{4}r^2 \\
&+ \frac{\alpha(x) - \beta(x) - i\gamma(x) + i\delta(x)}{4}r^3 \\
\end{align}$$, where $$r(y) = \text{exp}(2\pi iy)$$. Then, the function $$\psi(a + bi) = \psi_{xy}(4a,4b)$$ satisfies all of the requirements for $\psi$.

## Implementation

The following SageMath function takes in a square matrix and returns a symbolic expression $\psi: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ satisfying the above, though the expression gets unwieldy quite fast.

```
def psi(M):
    N = len(list(M))
    zeta = CyclotomicField(N).gen()
    dft_matrix = lambda n: matrix([[zeta^(x * y) for y in range(N)] for x in range(N)])
    
    q = var("q")
    psi_x = M * dft_matrix(N).inverse() * matrix([[q^k] for k in range(N)])
    psi_x = psi_x.transpose()
    
    r = var("r")
    psi_xy = psi_x * dft_matrix(N).inverse() * matrix([[r^k] for k in range(N)])
    
    z = var("z")
    return psi_xy(q=zeta^(z.real()*N), r=zeta^(z.imag()*N))[0]
```

## Illustrations

The following are the $\psi$ for all character tables, up to permutations of rows and columns, of all groups with four irreducible representations over the complex numbers, with domain reduced as described in the OP.

[image: Cyclic Group of Order 4] [image: Klein-Four Group] [image: Alternating Group on 4 Elements]

From left to right: Cyclic group of order 4, Klein-Four group, Alternating group on 4 elements. The expression for the dihedral group of order 10 was so long that the plotter refused to handle it. Perhaps a simpler method exists.